# "He ordered a whiskey." - metonymy/synecdoche/neither?

Tags: literary-device, metonymy, stylistic-devices

From what I understand, "He drank a glass" (container instead of thing contained) is metonymy, but would "He ordered a whiskey" instead of "a glass/shot of whiskey" be metonymy as well? Or would it be synecdoche, because it's the other way around (the thing contained instead of container)?

Or is it neither?

I saw conflicting examples:

> - Metonymy: Content per container: "Give me a whiskey". (not sure if it's a credible source, [x](https://whatdoesmean.net/what-is-metonymy/))

> - In any case the  example  simply involves me asking for two well-defined quantities of whisky. I’m not convinced of the relevance of metonymy here. What I care about is the whisky, not what it comes in, and when I drink the whisky I don’t drink the glass anyway. Metonymy would apply if I talked about drinking a couple of glasses. Consider “I drank two whiskies, one after the other” versus “I drank two glasses one after the other”. In both cases what has actually been drunk? (not sure if it's a credible source either, [x](https://telescoper.blog/2008/12/05/pluralia-tantum/))

So, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> would "He ordered a whiskey" instead of "a glass/shot of whiskey" be metonymy as well?

No. It is quite literal.

It does not differ from "He ordered a cabbage/a new wardrobe/a flock of ostriches."